# Why is the movie called Tangerine?

Tags: title, tangerine

I watched the movie carefully but still can't guess what is the meaning of the title Tangerine (2015).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few articles, such as [this one from The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/tangerine-the-sundance-film-festival-trans-movie-shot-entirely-on-an-iphone-5s-10013900.html) claim it is due to the production process:

> As for the film’s title, Tangerine was chosen after orange became the
> dominant colour when the saturation was pumped up in post-production.

They provide the following quote from the director (Sean Baker) to back this up:

> “The world [in the movie] is so colourful and the women are so
> colourful,” said Baker. “We wanted to match them.”

However, the director has addressed this explicitly [in a different interview](https://www.thewrap.com/tangerine-director-transgender-stars-deserve-recognition-oscars-spirit-awards/):

> **Question**: I’ve wondered about this ever since I saw the movie, and I’ve read a
> few different theories online, but why did you decide to call the
> movie “Tangerine”?
>
> **Answer**: We had a bunch of titles and that was one that
> everybody kept coming back to. It resonated with everybody, and
> everyone has their own interpretation. It doesn’t really stem from the
> dominant hue of the film, but there’s something about the title that
> reminds me of Christmas. I think I used to get tangerines in my
> stocking on Christmas, so there was a personal link for me. There are
> hints throughout the film, like the air freshener in the cab. It’s
> funny, filmmakers are the only artists who feel obligated to title
> their works of art. Musicians and poets and novelists don’t have to,
> but we’re the only ones who feel obligated, like we have to, and I
> want to get away from that. I’m fine with a title that’s open to
> interpretation.